# Why does this ssh command not work? (cat ./file | ssh <user@host> "cat | sudo -t -t 'cat > /root/location/file'")

Tags: ssh, sudo, pipe, root

I'm trying to do the following but it's not quite right.

```
cat ~/Desktop/blah.png | ssh -t -t trusktr@50.116.4.56 "cat | sudo -i 'cat | /path/to/blah.png'"
```

I have my public ssh key in the trusktr@50.116.4.56 user's .ssh folder, so no initial password is needed. When the `sudo -i` command finally starts, it prompts me for the root password, but immediately fails as if I had pressed enter but I didn't even touch the keyboard. I have a feeling maybe the `cat` command is being catted into the password prompt. The output looks like this:

```
trusktr@LENOVO-PC ~
$ cat ~/Desktop/win-8.1-missing-lockscreen-setting.png | ssh -t -t trusktr@50.116.4.56 "cat | sudo -i 'cat > /srv/http/default/htdocs/~/img/win-8.1-missing-lockscreen-setting.png'"
tcgetattr: Not a character device
[sudo] password for root:
You type like i drive.
[sudo] password for root:
Your mind just hasn't been the same since the electro-shock, has it?
[sudo] password for root:
Maybe if you used more than just two fingers...
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
Connection to 50.116.4.56 closed.
```

I don't have direct ssh access through the root user, only through a normal user with access to sudo using the root password.

How might I cat the image through ssh, through the non-root user, into the root location all in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are cating blah.png into `sudo`, which is not a valid password.

This should combine the needed commands onto one line:

```
scp ~/Desktop/blah.png trusktr@50.116.4.56:~/ && ssh -t -t trusktr@50.116.4.56 "sudo cp ~/blah.png /path/to/blah.png && rm ~/blah.png"
```

Comment: Does it "press enter" when a new line character is `cat`ted? How might I achieve what I'm trying to do in a single command?

Comment: @trusktr, yes, a newline is the same thing as enter, and you don't do it in a single command.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not entirely convinced there isn't a way to do it though.

Comment: @trusktr, you can't do it with a single *command*, but you can combine the commands into a single pipeline using the `&&` operator.

Comment: Oh, yeah, a one liner is what I meant. Could you give more details on how I'd change my command?

Comment: @trusktr, updated answer.

Comment: Aaah, sweet! That makes sense, and it works here in Git-Bash for Windows (I feared scp might no be available, but it is). Based on your answer, I've also come up with an ssh-only version: `cat ~/Desktop/blah.png | ssh trusktr@50.116.4.56 "cat > ~/blah"; ssh trusktr@50.116.4.56 "sudo mv ~/blah.png /path/to/blah.png"`.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1: `scp` the file to your account, then `ssh` in and put the file in place from the terminal.

Option #2: if your `sudo` caches auth, login and `sudo` to root before attempting the complex copy. (the second `sudo` shouldn't need a password)

(also, `sudo` uses *your* password, not root's)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I ended up doing the first option. My setup only caches during the session, so logging out destroys it. `sudo` can be configured to use the root password instead of the user's password by putting `Defaults rootpw` in /etc/sudoers.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of `sudo`... let people without the rootpw run commands as root.

Comment: Depends on the use case. I'm the only user, so it's more secure this way because an adversary now has to guess two passwords instead of just one.